# Access SQL Query to calculate % excluding the grouped column's values

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'll keep it short and sweet.  I have simplified but this is the general idea:

I have a table:

```
NAME    DATE
John    4/7/11
John    6/6/12
John    7/25/15
Sue     9/16/16
Sue     8/14/12
Joe     7/3/13
Mary    11/24/11
Mary    5/28/15
Mary    12/15/12
Mary    12/29/13
```

I have already written a query to calculate the the % of past dates GROUP BY [Name].  It looks something like this:

```
SELECT T1.Name, 
       Sum(IIf([Date]<Now(),1,0)) AS CountOfPastDates, 
       Count(T1.Date) AS CountEntries, 
       ([CountOfPastDates]/[CountEntries]) AS PercentPastDates 
FROM Table AS T1
GROUP BY T1.Name;
```

and gives results like:

```
NAME   % Past Dates
John   66.7
Sue    50.0
Joe    100.0
Mary   75.0
```

So far so good.

What I'm trying to write now is a query that calculates the % of past dates for everyone ELSE while excluding the persons results from the percentage.

The results should look like:

```
NAME   Others % Past Dates
John   71.4
Sue    75.0
Joe    66.7
Mary   66.7
```

Comment: Does this really have to be done in query form? It might be much easily done in code once you've obtained results from the database.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a subquery:

```
select  names.name
,       (
        select  sum(iif([Date]<Now(),1,0)) / count([Date])
        from    YourTable t1
        where   names.name <> t1.name
        ) as PercentagePastWithoutMe
from    (
        select  distinct name
        from    YourTable
        ) names
```

Not entirely sure if that works in Access.  And note that the percentage runs over all rows.  If you calculate the percentage per person, and then average that, you'd get a different number.

Comment: It worked!!!! (with some formatting for Access required) but wow it is slow.  Thanks for taking the time to reply :)